# How to find the probability of damaged goods transported by air?

Tags: probability

A company transports goods in three ways: air, sea and road. Based on the past records, of the total transported goods, 10% were by air, 30% by sea and 60% by road. It is found that 1% of goods transported by air were damaged, 5% of the goods transported by sea were damaged and 10% of the goods transported by road were damaged. If a good is found to be damaged, what is the probability that it was transported by air?

Comment: Use Bayes' Theorem. P(A|B) = P(B|A) * P(A) / P(B)
A is shipped by air. B is damaged.
P(B|A) = 0.01 (given)
P(A) = 0.1 (given)
P(B) = 0.1 * 0.01 + 0.3 * 0.05 + 0.6 * 0.1

Comment: The sketch given in the above comment looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea: form a probability tree, with three first branches $\,A, S, R\,$ (air, sea, road), with probabilities $\,0.1\,,\,0.3\,,\,0.6\,$ . From each of these trees two second branches grow: $\,D,G\,$ (damaged, good/not damaged), and write down the probabilities.

So the probability for a damaged good is

$$\color{red}{0.1\cdot0.01}+0.3\cdot0.05+0.6\cdot0.1=0.076$$

And now calculate the conditional probability

$$P(A/D)=\frac{P(A\cap D)}{P(D)}=\frac{\color{red}{0.001}}{0.076}=0.013158$$